# What's the best way to refactor redundant each/reverse_each code in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, linked-list, refactoring, doubly-linked-list

I have implemented these `each` and `reverse_each` methods for a doubly-linked list.

What would be the best way to refactor this?

```
def each
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  node = self
  until node.nil?
    yield node
    node = node.next
  end
end

def reverse_each
  return enum_for(:reverse_each) unless block_given?
  node = self
  until node.nil?
    yield node
    node = node.prev
  end
end
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this question.

Comment: Why do you want to refactor this methods? What are you optimizing for? Readability? Short code?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Code Review, I will keep it in mind for next time. I'm trying to minimize duplicate code. You might argue that this is already pretty readable, but you can also see that except for two things it is exactly the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to remove redundant code is to move it to a new method.

Something like this should work:

```
def each(&block)
  return enum_for(:each) unless block_given?
  traverse(:next, &block)
end

def reverse_each(&block)
  return enum_for(:reverse_each) unless block_given?
  traverse(:prev, &block)
end

private

def traverse(direction)
  node = self
  until node.nil?
    yield node
    node = node.send(direction)
  end
end
```

Comment: you can put `return enum_for(method) unless block_given?` in to `traverse` method. So you can call it like `traverse(:prev, :reverse_each, &block)`

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the simplest way. I tried something similar at first, but couldn't figure out the `&block` part.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
{ each: :next , reverse_each: :prev }.each_pair do |name, _method|
  define_method(name) do |&blk|
    return enum_for(name) unless block_given?
    node = self
    until node.nil?
      blk.call(node)
      node = node.send(_method)
    end
  end
end
```

Read about [`define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) and [`dynamic define methods`](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/2-metaprogramming-ruby/chapters/25-dynamic-methods/lessons/72-define-method)

Comment: This didn't work for some reason. It would just return nil. I think there is some issue with `enum_for` inside `define_method`.

Comment: What kind of error? What exactly not working? What is the issue with `enum_for`? Do you understand that this is just an example and I can't reproduce all logic just by two methods?

Comment: @Зелёный you can't use `block_given?` within `define_method`, because it refers to the `do ... end` block from `define_method`. Instead, use `define_method(name) do |&block|` and invoke it via `block.call(node)`

Comment: Ok, I tried this with `&block` now, but it's still not working. Even if I pass a block, `block_given?` returns `false`, so it will always return an `Enumerator` instead of executing the block.

Comment: Ok, with `return enum_for(name) if block.nil?` it works.